# Searching for similar columns in a huge csv file

Tags: bash, perl, csv, c++11

I have a huge csv file which has 5000 columns and 5,000,000 rows. I know that there are some columns in this file which are exactly the same. I want to identify such columns. Please not that I cannot fetch this huge file into the memory and runtime is also important.

Comment: all those tags and no code? add python and code something, you may get some answers.

Comment: If you have the CSV sorted then you do not need to keep to much in memory at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly the same?

I suppose you can verify it with hash functions.

step 1 - You can load the 5'000 values of first row and calculate 5'000 hash values; exclude the values (the columns) without a corresponding value.

step 2 - Load the value (only the column survived) and calculate the hash of the concatenation of preceding hash with the loaded value; exclude the values (the columns) without a corresponding value.

following steps: exactly as step 2: load and concatenate/hash, excluding columns without matches.

Comment: I followed your suggestion with bash and calculate hash for each column. I have the following command in a for loop. hash=$(tail -n +2 train.csv | cut -d',' -f$i | sha256sum)